# NGINX configuration location for following hierarchy of directories

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I was wondering whether the following location would work in NGINX
Configuration:

```
location ~ ^/(uk|us|de)/?(.*)? { 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1/$2;  
    proxy_cache off;  
    proxy_buffering on;     
}
```

The expected behaviour, so when user types us/test1 or us/test2/help or uk/output/help
If that directory hieararchy is present, would it open the intended page? Would it work if I would have applied it in NGINX conf? If no - please suggest how then I should change my configuration file to work?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you don't need to add (.*) at the end of the location and also no need to use $1 and $2 in the proxy URL. Following is the nginx configuration that I use to proxy requests to frontend and backend servers which is the same as your requirement at **location (add|update|manage)**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    http2 on;
    server_name dev.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/ssl/development.com+8.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/ssl/development+8-key.pem;
    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-Download-Options "noopen" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none" always;
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "none" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

    # Matches 
    # /add
    # /update
    # /manage
    # /add/user
    # /update/user
    # /manage/user
    location ~ ^/(add|update|manage) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Content-Type application/gzip;
        include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Content-Type text/css;
        include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    location ~ \.js {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Content-Type application/x-javascript;
        include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    location / {
        include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/conf.d/security.conf;
}
```

**Contents of /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf**

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Contents of **/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/conf.d/security.conf**

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
```

To test whether the location match is working properly or not you can use below link
https://nginx.viraptor.info/

**Note:** Keep in mind to add / at the end as it should only be matched when the other regex(Ex: ~ ^/(add|update|manage)) that we are using does not match the URL that you have requested